# Unir dos arrays evitando usar merge y foreach

Tags: php, array, concatenación

El problema se explica sencillo, tengo dos arrays:

```
array(0,1,2,3,4); // primero
array(5,6,7,8,9); // segundo
```

Necesito concatenarlos:

```
array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) // primero y segundo unidos
```

El problema es que no puedo utilizar `foreach` ni `while` ya que son arrays que contienen más de 99 registros y eso retrasa el tiempo de respuesta. Me gustaría saber si *PHP* nativamente tiene alguna función que lo haga, algo como:

```
unir_array(primero, segundo);
```

Siempre busco en inglés en *Google* pero hasta el momento no consigo lograrlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar **`array_merge()`** que combina los arrays que quieras, sólo debes ponerlos como parámetros:

```
$array3 = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

También se puede concatenarlos (unirlos) mediante el operador **`+`**:

```
$array3 = $array1 + $array2;
```

En la documentación de *PHP* está mejor explicado:

- [PHP: array_merge](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: No puedo utilizar el merge, cuando hago merge se reemplazan los datos del primer array, ambos arrays no tienen llaves, es decir las llaves son secuenciales, array(a,b,c,d,e) y array(f,g,h,i) si hago el merge, el segundo array reemplaza el primero automaticamente.

Comment: Oh, no leí bien tu pregunta, pero para hacerlo solo necesitas "concatenarlos", deja modifico mi respuesta, eso último también está explicado en la documentación.

Comment: Lo siento, ya lo he resuelto se me ocurrio utilizar range para las llaves, ya abajo te coloco la respuesta, quizá eso ayude a otros.

Answer (score 0):

El `array_a` es el primer array, cuando haces el combine lo que *PHP* toma es cambiar las `keys` de algún array, `range` crea un array con números de *x a x*.

¿Que hice? Primero `count(array_a)` para saber el último índice del primer array, luego `count(array_b)` para saber hasta dónde llegar. Teniendo esas `keys`, se las asigno al `array_b`.

Listo, ya le cambié las llaves al segundo array, ahora con el indicador `+`, ya puedo unirlos porque tienen llaves distintas.

```
$final = $array_a+array_combine(range(count($array_a),count($array_b)), $array_b);
```